# gcc: C preprocessor, stringify the result of a macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I try to print "Linux is number linux" in C language with C preprocessor, but it always print "Linux is number 1". It only happened with GCC, not tinycc.

Expected: Linux is number linux!
Actually: Linux is number 1!

Below Dockerfile is just for testing between different compiler and version easier. I have tried GCC version 4.9.4, 5.5.0, 6.5.0, 7.5.0, 8.5.0, 9.5.0, 10.2.0, 10.5.0, 11.4.0, 12.3.0 and 13.1.0. it will print something like below.

```
gcc (GCC) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Linux is number 1!
```

```
tcc version 0.9.27 mob:afc1362 (x86_64 Linux)
Linux is number linux!
```

linux1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define stringify_x(x)  #x
#define STRINGIFY(s)    stringify_x(s)

int main(void)
{
    printf(STRINGIFY(Linux is number linux!\n));
    return 0;
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcc:13.1.0
COPY . /usr/src/linux1
WORKDIR /usr/src/linux1
RUN gcc -o linux1 linux1.c
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/gcc --version; ./linux1"]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM bensuperpc/tinycc:20220726-97fe2cc
COPY . /usr/src/linux1
WORKDIR /usr/src/linux1
RUN tcc -o linux1 linux1.c
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "tcc --version; ./linux1"]
```